# Android JSON-RPC tunneled in websocket

Tags: android, websocket, json-rpc

How well does Android support JSON-RPC tunneled in websocket protocol?
Do you have any experience with that?

THANKS!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a pretty specific thing to "support". Websockets are just a bi-directional communications protocol implemented over HTTP (the HTTP part of the request does an "upgrade" to allow the TCP socket to be reused, in much the same way as HTTPS).

**How?**

Just pick any implementation of Websockets for Android that you're comfortable with. Perhaps [Autobahn](http://autobahn.ws/) ?

To "tunnel" JSON-RPC over that, for example, you could sub-class the [JSONRPCClient](https://code.google.com/p/android-json-rpc/source/browse/trunk/android-json-rpc/src/org/alexd/jsonrpc/JSONRPCClient.java) class in [android-json-rpc](https://code.google.com/p/android-json-rpc/wiki/Documentation) (overriding the `doJSONRequest` method in much the same way [JSONRPCHttpClient](https://code.google.com/p/android-json-rpc/source/browse/trunk/android-json-rpc/src/org/alexd/jsonrpc/JSONRPCHttpClient.java) does) naming your implementation `JSONRPCWebsocketsClient` (to make use of whichever Websockets implementation you chose).

**Why?**

A more important question would be why you need to tunnel JSON-RPC over Websockets?

- Are you going to use the (asymmetric, server-to-client) "notification" messages from the older JSON-RPC proposals? (I would!)
- Are you stuck talking to some very specific server-side implementation?
- Is this just to get past some silly corporate firewall?

If it's just for "notification" messages, then why not do this over plan TCP (more lightweight) rather than Websockets (which are significantly more complicated).

If it's to work with some specific server implementation, your options are "live with it" or to put a proxy server of some sort in between your clients and the server.

If it's to make use of HTTP to bypass a corporate firewall (perhaps in combination with needing server-to-client "notification" messages) then while this might be a "good" solution, an easier one might be to actually get support from ITS within said corporation to expose a secured, well-known endpoint without whatever restrictions are currently holding you back.

Comment: Thank you very much for the interesting and detailed explanation!!!
Your first solution is the way: the benefit is, that you need just one single connection for requests and events (notifications). Is it really so problematical with firewalls and proxys?

Comment: @Jules `Is it really so problematical with firewalls and proxys?` No, it's not at all -- That's the point. You might use Websockets instead of some other protocol that *does* have issues going through firewalls. Websockets is just HTTP "downgraded" to plain TCP -- as long as HTTP can get through, so can Websockets. An example would be JSON-RPC over plain TCP. As that doesn't do an HTTP 'handshake', some corporate firewalls wouldn't let it pass through.

Comment: Thank you again David-SkyMesh!

Comment: Is the websocket the "state of the art" method for bidirectional client-server communication (also known as server-push)? 
Do you have other (better) solutions for us? It have to work in the linux, android and windows world.

Comment: If it has to work on mobiles, Websockets is probably best at this time. In an ideal 'server push' implementation, the server directly connects to the clients. That's really only possible with a static, public IP (something you're very unlikely to have on mobile), unless you the mobile device creates some sort of ongoing tunnel (like RIM's Blackberry).